# How to do component scanning for sibling package in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

Currently I have quite a bit of services written in Spring Boot 2.1.3 (in mono-repo) and I have a common package that's used in most of the services.

So my packages are organized in the following:

```
root
root.common
root.serviceA
root.serviceA.<subpackages>
root.serviceB
root.serviceB.<subpackages>
...
root.serviceX
root.serviceX.<subpackages>
```

In each service I have `Program.java` where it's tagged with `@SpringBootApplication` (e.g. `root/serviceA/Program.java)`

The problem now I'm having is that I have a component in `root.common` (e.g. `root/common/JSONSerializer.java`) which needs to be loaded in all the services. I tried tagging the file with `@JsonComponent` but obviously it doesn't work because it's outside `root.service*` package.

I managed to get it working by manually adding `@Import` tag in the main file but that means that for each service I have to manually add `@Import({root.common.JSONSerializer.class})` which is tedious and error prone. Is there a way to include this file in the component scanning process?

Comment: Just use `@ComponentScan` along with `@SpringBootApplication`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set each Program class by following way:

```
 @SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {"root.serviceA", "root.common"})
```

**REFERENCES**

[SpringBootApplication documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/SpringBootApplication.html)

Comment: awesome, why didn't I think of that before :-) thanks!